# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.Login

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

Hi I'm building an web application using Servlets and jsp, i've created a login servlet but when i'm trying to run it using tomcat it's throwing class not found Exception. I've tried maximum solutions found on stack overflow and other sources but no help. 
I'm providing code for you reference.

Login.java :-

```
package services;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import MyDao.Dao;
import bin.userbin;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
*/
//@WebServlet("/Login") 
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 102831973239L;


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("Paswword");
        String stat = request.getContextPath();
        System.out.println(stat+"context path");
        String stat1 = request.getServletPath();
        System.out.println(stat1+"servlet path");
        String stat2 = request.getPathInfo();
        System.out.println(stat2+" path info");




        try {

            userbin user = Dao.getname(username, password);

            /*Cookie ck = new Cookie("cookie1",u.getF_name() );
            response.addCookie(ck);*/



            if(user !=null){
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            //ServletContext context = getServletContext();
            /*String f = context.getInitParameter("F_name");
            String f1 = context.getInitParameter("L_name");*/
            PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();



            p.println("<form action = 'logout'><input type = 'submit' name = 'logout' value = 'logout'></input></form>");

            RequestDispatcher dispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("fileRecords.html");
                dispatch.include(request, response);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("invalid user! you need to sign in first");
                RequestDispatcher rdispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.html");
                rdispatch.include(request, response);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Web.xml :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>PC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>services.Login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
<!--   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>searchfile</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>services.SearchFile</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>searchfile</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/searchfile</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>filerecords</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>services.FileRecords</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>filerecords</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/filerecords</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping> -->

</web-app>
```

index.html :-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login Form</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <div class="login100-pic js-tilt" data-tilt>
                    <img src="images/img-01.png" alt="IMG">
                </div>

                <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="Login" method="post"> 
                    <span class="login100-form-title">
                        Member Login
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Valid email is required: ex@abc.xyz">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="UserName">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Password is required">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        <span class="symbol-input100">
                            <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <!--  <button class="login100-form-btn" onclick="operation.html">
                            Login
                        </button> -->
                        <input type="submit" " value="Login" />
                    </div>

                    <!-- <div class="text-center p-t-12">
                        <span class="txt1">
                            Forgot
                        </span>
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Username / Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-136">
                        <a class="txt2" href="#">
                            Create your Account
                            <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-5" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div> -->
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Error i'm getting:-

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: services.Login
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1032)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:761)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

thanks in advance..

Comment: What is `web.xml` path?

Comment: @MustafaÇil hi web.xml is in WEB-INF.

Comment: Did you add all required jar files in your WEB-INF/lib folder?